# What's this lock mechanism on Lenovo thinkstation P500?

Tags: lenovo-desktop-computer

Openning the chassis of my Lenovo thinkstation P500, I noticed that there is a kind of lock mechanism located at one side of the system board. I don't know what's this, and how to "open" it. I did not find any info in the user manual of P500 yet.

A picture is below:

[image]

Comment: Is it for locking a small board in place? That is what I see on my Lenovo M70 desktop.

Comment: Don't know. I just browse the M70 user guide, although there are several locks, seems no such a lock is described there.

Comment: The M70 Lock secures my SSD drive.

Comment: Looks like this holds the motherboard in place, no? Pretty common to not use screws in enterprise equipment.

Comment: Seems not...there are plenty of screws (about 15 I guess) to secure the mother board to the chassis... there is a spring inside the lock, the top of the lock can be pushed down with a bit distance, and it pops back when the push is released. i.e., at least the top of "lock" is not fixed with mother board.

Comment: From [this thread](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkStation-Workstations/upgrading-a-P500-to-a-P700/m-p/4413991?page=1#4414568), it seems that this is the "motherboard latch" mentioned in the reply. If it is the latch, then according the the description, to open the latch, one has to first remove the mother board... not sure what it latches though...